# Playing Blu-Ray discs on an Acer Aspire laptop

Tags: laptop, acer-aspire, blu-ray

I bought this (otherwise very nice) laptop around 3 years ago, but Blu-Ray never worked on it. (Even though it was promoted as Blu-Ray compatible with stickers on it and what not.)
‎
Acer/Windows detects the Blu-Ray drive, but neither Windows Media Player nor VLC can play any Blu-Ray discs (tried the trailer reel and other discs).

I can see on the net it may require Acer Arcade Deluxe? Is that necessary for Blu-Ray to work? (I don't believe I have that any more. I probably figured it was related to gaming or something like that and removed it long ago...) Is Acer Arcade Deluxe the only software that works with Acer Blu-Ray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default WMP or VLC install will not play commercial [AACS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Access_Content_System)-encrypted Bluray discs. Without getting into a discussion about potentially illegal (depending on your jurisdiction) usage of hacked AACS key databases with these players, let me just say that you should stick to a licensed software Bluray player that will be able to play newer releases as well.

Acer Arcade Deluxe seems to be a cut-down/customised version of [CyberLink's PowerDVD](http://www.cyberlink.com/products/powerdvd/features_en_US.html), so you should install it and play your discs. Remember that both hardware and software players need to be updated periodically to keep up with newer AACS keys used on the latest discs, so if Acer Arcade Deluxe is unable to play a disc, update it from the [CyberLink site](http://www.cyberlink.com/acer/update/) as detailed [here](http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8545/~/acer-arcade-deluxe-not-playing-blu-ray) (you'll need to use Internet Explorer as the site uses an ActiveX control).

I couldn't find an official download link for Acer Arcade Deluxe (seems it only comes bundled with Acer PCs), so if you don't have it on a DVD somewhere you'll need to contact Acer or buy something else such as PowerDVD.

Comment: I already tried he CyberLink update URL which said there was nothing to update. (Probably because I removed it.) I will try go through my acer disks, but I think a complete reinstall will be necessary. Oh well. I will return if I have more questions/information.